# HTA output is not appearing

Tags: vbscript, hta

```
<body bgcolor="white">

<!--Add your controls here-->

<table cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 bgcolor="black">
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="white">
<script type="text/vbscript">
    document.write(userName)
    window.Alert(userName)
</script>
  </td>
  <td bgcolor="white">row1_col2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="white">row2_col1</td>
  <td bgcolor="white">row2_col2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="white">row3_col1</td>
  <td bgcolor="white">row3_col2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<!--{{InsertControlsHere}}-Do not remove this line-->
</body>
</html>
```

The username only appears in the  tags above the HTML. When I use window.Alert userName, the value does display but only if that code is in the  section above. When I perform the same window.Alert in the body, I get "" (empty string).

I can't figure out whats going on. I updated the code as per the suggestions on one of the comments.

Comment: I didnt use a template. I didnt realize that <% %> is exclusively for ASP. I have some limited ASP background and assumed that <% is for VBScript, VB related stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% %>` is ASP syntax, not HTA syntax. In HTA you could use a nested `<script>` tag, though:

```
<td><script type="text/vbscript">document.write userName</script></td>
```

BTW, I strongly recommend to use stylesheets for formatting tags (like setting the `<td>` background color). It's much cleaner, and also much easier to maintain.

Comment: Right now I am more focused on getting the output before I beautify it. Also your solution didn't work. Output was empty.

Comment: @softwareisfun Then you don't have a global variable `userName` (or it doesn't have a value). Please update your question with the code where the variable is defined/initialized.